# How to determine the type of an object using instanceof?

Tags: typescript, types, instanceof

I have a tree of objects whose node can be one of two types. The types (classes) have the same structure. Please tell me how can I check the node type? I've read a lot of discussions here. If I understand correctly, then I need "instanceof". But it doesn't work.

```
export class ProductTree {
  public value: ProductDirection | ProductBrand | null;
  public children: ProductTree[];
}

export class ProductDirection {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;

  constructor() {
      this.id = 0;
      this.name = '';
  }
}

export class ProductBrand{
    public id: number;
    public name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = "";
    }
}
```

Simple example of using "instaceof". Elements at the first level are only of type ProductDirection, second level are only of type ProductBrand

[image]

```
var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    for (let val of this.productsTree) {
      if (val.value instanceof ProductDirection) {
        a++;
      }
      for (let val1 of val.children) {
        if (val1.value instanceof ProductBrand) {
          b++;
        }
      }
    }
```

Result: a = b = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely with how you created your `productsTree` and not with how you determine the element type. Your inspector popup suggests that your elements are of type Object, so you most likely created them as non-typed objects instead of typed ProductTree/ProductDirection/ProductBrand:

```js
// For that data your instanceof should work
let v: ProductTree[] = [
  { value: new ProductDirection, children: [
    { value: new ProductBrand(), children: null],
    { value: new ProductBrand(), children: null]
  ]}
]

// For that data your instanceof shouldn't work
let v = [
  { value: {id: 1, name: "direction_1"}, children: [
    { value: {id: 2, name: "brand_1"}, children: null],
    { value: {id: 2, name: "brand_2"}, children: null]
  ]}
]
```